# Excel VBA Sheets(Array()).Select Subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, subscript

Having a little problem with this tiny bit of code in Excel VBA.

All I'm trying to do is select multiple sheets in a workbook and export them as one PDF. 
I have many Sheets that I don't want to hide or move around, so earlier in my code I looped and saved the particular names in an array. I was getting this error, so i thought I would resort to simply hard coding their names to see if that worked.

But even with hard coded names i get the 'Subscript out of range error', so there must be something else going wrong.

```
wb.Sheets(Array("Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", "Sheet 3", "Sheet 4", "Sheet 5")).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _ ............
```

Are there any known errors relating to the above statement? (I've only included the first 2 lines as it doesn't execute past the first line)
OR are there any suggestions to stop this error occuring?

Note: I have changed the Sheet names as they relate to sensitive data. However an example is "S&C *vendor1*"

Comment: Are you sure your `wb` reference is pointing to the right workbook?  That syntax works fine for me.

Comment: Yep, Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(F.Path)  I'm also iterating through many workbooks, but i reference the wb in many other parts of my code which execute fine.

Comment: Then there's likely another piece of information we don't have access to which explains the problem.  Try removing the sheet names one-by-one until the error disappears.

Comment: Maybe populate the array with the name of the worksheet directly, instead of manually putting in the names. `wb.sheets(1).Name` for example for the first worksheet, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. It turns out that I accidently had it inside a loop and must have been selecting multiple times and then ran out of range.

Thanks for all the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to **spell** worksheet names properly:

```
Sub dural()
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   wb.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
End Sub
```

*There is no space in the default worksheet name.*

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I have changed the worksheet names as they relate to possibly sensitive data. That being said, the actual worksheet names do have spaces in them, could that affect it somehow?

Comment: Is the error in the ***Select*** or in the ***Export*** ??

Comment: The Select, I just included the Export line to show what i would do with the selection.

Comment: This is most likely because at least one of the the worksheet names (in the array) either does not exist in that workbook or is spelled incorrectly.